# loading issue on login page after password is entered

Tags: boot

Hi everyone I have a desktop of lenovo thinkpad m80 series with ubuntu 16.04 installed . while powering on the system everything goes fine untill the login screen appears . There once I enter the password in the text box under my username , just the mouse pointer appears with just pink blank screen and will not load anything furthur . I tried with reinstalling the O.S. but still facing issue . Can anyone help me out